# How do i set the value of toggle score buttons within teams?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do i set  the value of the toggle score buttons for each team  ?

For example when team A is pressed then user can choose from score buttons.
Also if team B is pressed then user can choose from score buttons. But only the team selected gets the points.

```
 void scoreTeamA() {
    setState(() {
      outputTeamA += _choiceA;
    });
  }

 void scoreTeamB() {
    setState(() {
      outputTeamB += _choiceB;
    });
  }
```

Team buttons

```
          ToggleButtons(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'team A',
                  textScaleFactor: 3,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'team B ',
                textScaleFactor: 3,
              ),
            ],
            onPressed: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                    buttonIndex < isSelected1.length;
                    buttonIndex++) {
                  if (buttonIndex == index) {
                    isSelected1[buttonIndex] = true;
                  } else {
                    isSelected1[buttonIndex] = false;
                  }
                }
              });
            },
```

Score buttons

```
 ToggleButtons(
                children: [
                  Text('5'),
                  Text('6'),
                  Text('7'),
                ],
                onPressed: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    isSelected2[index] = !isSelected2[index];
                    switch (index) {
                      case 0:
                        _choiceA = 5;
                        _choiceB = 5;
                        break;
                      case 1:
                        _choiceA = 6;
                        _choiceB = 6;
                        break;
                      case 2:
                        _choiceA = 7;
                        _choiceB = 7;
                        break;
                    }
                  });
                },
                isSelected: isSelected2,
              ),
```

Win Button

```
 MaterialButton(
                  shape: CircleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          width: 1.0,
                          style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      scoreTeamA();
                       scoreTeamB();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'win',
                    textScaleFactor: 3,
                  ),
                ),
```

Thank you
Mohammad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's very little information to work with but I'll try:

```
                children: [
                  isSelected1[0] ? Text('5') : Text('five'),
                  Text('6'),
                  Text('7'),
                ],
```

This should let you see **something** that changes. From there you should be able to get the rest done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i still didn't get it .